# Putting $m$ distinct balls to $n$ identical boxes with each box has at least $2$ balls

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, stirling-numbers

If we were to put $m$ distinct balls to $n$ identical boxes with no empty boxes, there would be $S(m,n)$ ways to do it where $S(m,n)$ is the Stirling number of the second kind.

But when it comes to the case where we should put the balls with each box has at least $2$ balls, I am stuck here because this is not an ordinary surjection anymore. What I tried so far was trying to examine the problem case by case.

Let $\sigma(m,n)$ be the number of ways of putting $m$ distinct balls to $n$ identical boxes with each box has at least $2$ balls. For the case $m < 2n$, we have $0$ way to do this, obviously. For the case $m = 2n$, I think the number of ways $$\sigma(m,n) = \sigma(2n,n) = \frac{1}{n!} \prod_{\scriptstyle i = 0\atop\scriptstyle i \ even}^{2n-2} \binom{2n-i}{2}$$ because we are partioning $2n$ as $2+2+...+2$ where there are $n$ many $2$'s and since the boxes are identical, we are dividing it by $n!$ in order to avoid overcounting. It is also obvious that for $m \ge 2$ and $n = 1$, $\sigma(m,n) = \sigma(m,1) = 1$. But for other cases, I cannot find any way to find a closed form expression or a recurrence relation for $\sigma(m,n)$ because I think I need to consider both number of ways of partioning $m$ into $n$ classes and number of ways of seperating balls for each partioning in order to find a closed form expression. And in order to find a recurrence relation, I have to proceed as deriving a recurrence relation for Stirling numbers of the second kind but here there are not two cases as in the Stirling numbers $\bigg(S(m,n) = S(m-1,n-1) + nS(m-1,n)$, here the two cases are "when we put $m-1$ balls into $n-1$ boxes" and "when we put $m-1$ balls into $n$ boxes" $\bigg)$. If I could find a way to divide the problem into some disjoint cases, I would have found a recurrence relation but no luck there so any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We get  for the combinatorial  class of set partitions  into non-empty
parts and hence Stirling numbers the specifiaction

$$\mathfrak{P}_{=k}(\mathfrak{P}_{\ge 1}(\mathcal{Z}))$$

and thus the generating function

$$\sum_{n\ge 0} {n\brace k} \frac{z^n}{n!}
= \frac{(\exp(z)-1)^k}{k!}.$$

This will start producing non-zero terms when $n\ge k.$ Using the same
construction we get for set partitions with at least two balls

$$\mathfrak{P}_{=k}(\mathfrak{P}_{\ge 2}(\mathcal{Z}))$$

and thus the generating function

$$\sum_{n\ge 0} {n\brace k}_{\ge 2} \frac{z^n}{n!}
= \frac{(\exp(z)-z-1)^k}{k!}.$$

Extracting coefficients from this we find

$$n! [z^n] \frac{(\exp(z)-z-1)^k}{k!}
= n! [z^n] \frac{1}{k!}
\sum_{q=0}^k {k\choose q} (\exp(z)-1)^q (-1)^{k-q} z^{k-q}
\\ = \frac{n!}{k!}
\sum_{q=0}^k {k\choose q} [z^{n+q-k}] (\exp(z)-1)^q (-1)^{k-q}
\\ = n!
\sum_{q=0}^k \frac{1}{(k-q)!}  (-1)^{k-q}
 [z^{n+q-k}] \frac{(\exp(z)-1)^q}{q!}
\\ = n!
\sum_{q=0}^k \frac{1}{(k-q)!}  (-1)^{k-q}
\frac{1}{(n+q-k)!} {n+q-k\brace q}$$

This yields

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
{n\brace k}_{\ge 2} =
\sum_{q=0}^k {n\choose k-q}  (-1)^{k-q}
{n+q-k\brace q}.}$$

For example with $k=3$ we get the sequence starting at six

$$15, 105, 490, 1918, 6825, 22935, 74316, \ldots$$

which is [OEIS  A000478](https://oeis.org/A000478) where the preceding
calculation is confirmed. With $k=4$ we find starting at eight,

$$105, 1260, 9450, 56980, 302995, 1487200, 6914908, \ldots$$

which  is  [OEIS  A058844](https://oeis.org/A058844) which  once  more
confirms these data.

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with [cycle notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugacy_class) for permutations? Two permutations are conjugate if and only if they have the same cycle type. All permutations with the same cycle type belong to the same *conjugacy class.* There is a bijection between $\text{Par}(m)$ and the conjugacy classes of $\text{Sym}(m)$ (the $m!$ permutations).

Now let $\mu = (\mu_{1}^{a_{1}}, \ldots, \mu_{k}^{a_{k}}) \in \text{Par}(m)$, where exponent denotes multiplicity. The [size of a conjugacy class](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Conjugacy_class_size_formula_in_symmetric_group) is given by:

$$\frac{m!}{\prod_{i=1}^{k} (\mu_{i}^{a_{i}} \cdot a_{i}!)}$$

Let $\text{Par}_{2, n}(m)$ be the set of partitions of $m$ with $n$ parts, and each part is at least $2$. You are interested in permutations with cycle type $\mu \in \text{Par}_{2,n}(m)$.

Answer (score 1):

is it $\sigma(m,n) = (m-1) * \sigma(m-2,n-1) + n * \sigma (m-1,n)$ ?

Comment: This seems correct and I understood the second case ($n \sigma(m-1,n)$) but in the first case, where does $m-1$ come from?